# Button is not getting hidden

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am trying to hide the save button and show the processing button.

But the save button is not getting hidden.

onclick of the save button.

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save', 'custom_table_example')?>" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit" >

<input type="submit1" style="display:none; value="<?php _e('PROCESSING....', '')?>" id="submit1" class="button-primary" name="submit1" >
```

calling jQuery in WordPress (externally)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_search' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_table_example_saveprocess' );
function custom_table_example_saveprocess() {
wp_register_script( 'custom_table_example_save',   plugins_url('/js/save_process.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('custom_table_example_save');
```

jQuery file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log("plugin script loaded1");
    $('#submit').click( function() {
        //alert("hi");
        $("#submit").hide();
        $("#submit1").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @vbrmnd actually when i click on save there is some more process. code is huge so restricted to this.

Comment: $('#submit').click( function() {
$("#submit").hide();  $("#submit1").hide(); even this didn't work

Comment: On the page you're running the script on, are you receiving any console errors? (CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome)

Comment: @Tyler Roper no errors  but save button is not getting hided.

Comment: Is your processing button getting shown? Do you have other elements with the same id `submit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `onclick` event for the button that hides `#submit` when clicked, and shows `#submit1`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Number One" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit" onclick="$('#submit').hide(); $('#submit1').show();" />

<input type="submit1" style="display:none;" value="Number Two" id="submit1" class="button-primary" name="submit1" />
```

If you'd rather use an external jquery file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
       $('#submit').hide();
       $('#submit1').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any javascript code in your answer so I'm not sure. This will handle the hiding/showing of the buttons all on its own and requires no other javascript code, it just replaces the two inputs that you have in your original question. Be sure to keep the jquery reference though.

Comment: its not there in the answer but i pasted code in comments.

Comment: @JMR You can remove that code. The code I posted is completely stand-alone. Also, the code you posted is saying `$('#submit1').hide();` instead of `$('#submit1').show();`, just so you're aware.

Comment: On what event specifically are you trying to hide `#submit` and show `#submit1`? The click of `#form`, or the click of `#submit`? **Please click "Run Code Snippet" underneath my answer to see a working example.**

Comment: #submit itself but was trying even with form

Comment: @jmr Run the code snippet in my latest answer. It should work as you want, and you wouldn't need the jQuery file from your question at all.

Comment: i will try once..but some time wordpress does not support any javascript and jquery events to be called on the same page.

Comment: i got an error in console  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Comment: That is unrelated. It appears nowhere in the code either you or I have provided. Please see my updated answer. This answers your original question - unfortunately additional errors are separate altogether.

Comment: it did not work for me (Jquery code) i guess i have pasted the same answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118706/discussion-between-jmr-and-tyler-roper).